How i get my channel subscribers back? Telegram
my telegram account is since 3 days banned :(  i have a big channel with this account and a lot of subscribers but my new account is not admin of this channel,i am very scary that i could loose all my contacts and subscribers that i have a few of years because i dont know every usernames of my list.
I try it with python but im a newbie and thats freak me out. Please can anyone help me to solved this Problem?
(i have write the customerservice from telegram but didnt get a answer)
look on youtube  and other websites to solved this problem but didnt help
